# Rails parsing json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

After requesting some API, i get a json hash. What I want is to loop through that hash to  get the tags but I get `no implicit conversion of String into Integer`. any help or a better way of doing this, please?

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "result": [
   {
    "verdict": "OK",
    "problem": {
      "tags": [
        "implementation", ...
      ]
    }
   },  
   .
   .
  ]
}
```

models/codeforces_api.rb

```
def self.retrieve_results(current_user)

    json = JSON.parse(open("http://codeforces.com/api/user.status?handle=#{current_user.code_forces_handle}&key='my-key'&secret='my-secret'").read).to_json     

    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(json)["result"].each do |record|
       if record["verdict"] == "OK"
          record ["problem"].each do |problem|
             problem ["tags"].each do |tag|
                puts tag
             end              
           end
       end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
record["problem"]["tags"].each do |tag|
```